# Html disable android deep link

Tags: android, mobile-website, deep-linking

Is there any way to tell a webpage link (the < a > tag) to NOT deep link to an android app and to stay in the browser.

I'm referring to what can be done in on the website, not the app.

Comment: did you find the solution for this ? I am looking for same thing that my mobile website should not open links in app. My app is supporting deeplinks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block mobile website to open my app android deeplink - Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301286/block-mobile-website-to-open-my-app-android-deeplink-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

The application will kick in any time the intent url pattern matches the deeplink pattern in its manifest.
I think that if you know what is the pattern, you can work around something