# Block mobile website to open my app android deeplink - Google Chrome

Tags: android, android-intent, google-chrome-app, deep-linking, deeplink

I have supported deeplinks in my app

```
<activity android:name=".DeepLinkActivity" android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.example.Launcher"
        android:targetActivity=".DeepLinkActivity">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/SCHEMA" />
            <data android:host="@string/WEB_DOMAIN" />
            <data android:host="@string/WWW_WEB_DOMAIN" />
            <data android:path="/" />
            <data android:path="/x" android:pathPattern="/x/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

So whenever user clicks on www.example.com the android app asks to open as app or web that is fine, but I do not want when my users are on mobile site they should be asked to open in app. I have gone through many stackoverflow posts but everyone says its not possible but still many websites are handling this scenario.

As per this [Article](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/) the behaviour depends on user gestures, if user is clicking on any link then Chrome displays a chooser while if user is typing url on browser then it doesn't.

Comment: Probably that mobiles sites use different url?

Comment: No mobile site and app have same urls.

Comment: Can you show that site and app?

Comment: www.desidime.com , the https schema is not live yet so wont work for you.

Comment: Nice prove of your words if even you said that it won't work for me.

Comment: I don't want to create different domain or urls for web and app as many other apps are doing.

Comment: @Divers, so right now we are supporting only custom schemas not http and https , then it is not redirecting from any where only internally in app. But after supporting http and https this issue is coming.

Comment: You said `still many websites are handling this scenario.`, and Im asking show me at least one which I can check.

Comment: Please check nl.pepper.com, myntra.com, hotUKdeals.

Comment: No , their mobile site is also using same domain and urls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After lot of research I have solved it. You can use either way.

**Handle in mobile website :** So if you want to render your user to Chrome always when they are on your msite you can achieve this by redirecting all your urls to

- googlechrome://navigate?url=https://www.example.com
- intent://www.example.com/x#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;S.browser_fallback_url=https://www/example.com/x;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;

**Handle in app**

- Create single transparent activity to handle all your deeplinks
- Handle all the links using pathpattern = '.*'
- Redirect user back to Chrome for urls you do not want to handle in app.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/SCHEMA" />
                <data android:host="@string/WEB_DOMAIN" />
                <data android:host="@string/WWW_WEB_DOMAIN" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**DeepLinkActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    try {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
            if (uri == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uri can not be null");
            Intent intent = null;
            if (getString(R.string.SCHEMA).equals(uri.getScheme()) || uri.toString().matches(Links.REGEX)) {
                intent = linkIntent(uri);
            }
            if (intent == null) SystemUtil.launchUrlInDefaultBrowser(uri, this); else startActivity(intent);

        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.can_not_open_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.can_not_open_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        finish();
    }
}

 /**
 * This will open the provided url in browser except the current app.
 * @param url Uri
 * @param context  Activity Context
 */
public static void launchUrlInDefaultBrowser(Uri url, Context context) {
    try {
        ResolveInfo packageInfo = null;
        final Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        browserIntent.setData(url);
        // Try to find anything that we can launch the URL with. Pick up the first one that can.
        final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(browserIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (!resolveInfoList.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo list : resolveInfoList) {
                if (!BuildConfig.APP_PACKAGE_NAME.equals(list.activityInfo.packageName)) {
                    packageInfo = list;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (packageInfo != null) {
            browserIntent.setClassName(packageInfo.activityInfo.packageName, packageInfo.activityInfo.name);
            context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.can_not_open_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.can_not_open_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those solutions looks like a huge hack to me. What if Google ever decides to switch their default browser to something else (as they did once)? What if the user has some other (custom) mobile browser? What if device manufacurer installs something else as a default browser?

Comment: Yeah it's a hack but it is working fine. The intent issue is only with Chrome.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution for it?