# Prevent a URL/webpage from opening in application

Tags: javascript, android, deep-linking

I have an application which supports all urls having `xyz` as domain.

So now if I sent my users a message or a mail containing the link of the above domain like `xyz.com/abc` or maybe `xyz.com`, for mobile IOS users the link opens in browser but for mobile android users there is a pop up which asks the user to choose whether they want to open the link in my app or the browser.

I have an issue with what the android is doing. I don't want that pop up for some particular links, I want that link to open in browser instead of the application. Is there a way I can achieve it by setting some headers in the response or maybe setting some meta tags in the html.

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: For further clearance : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357191/does-meta-name-google-play-app-work : look at the second answer with 34 upvotes, If maybe I can pass `content="app-id=com.google.chrome"` in my html tags to force the page to open in chrome. I know it is kind of a hack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block mobile website to open my app android deeplink - Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301286/block-mobile-website-to-open-my-app-android-deeplink-google-chrome)

Answer (score -2):

You can get you domain host from the URL:

```
        Uri url = Uri.parse("www.xyz.com/lol");
        String host = url.getHost();

        if (host.equals("xyz.com")) {
            openInAppMethod();
        } else {
            openInBrowserMethod();
        }
```

And then choose the way to open your url.

Comment: For further clearance : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357191/does-meta-name-google-play-app-work : look at the second answer with 34 upvotes, If maybe I can pass `content="app-id=com.google.chrome"` in my html tags to force the page to open in chrome. I know it is kind of a hack.