# How can web-publisher prevent Amazon Affiliate DEEP-LINKS from opening in Amazon App

Tags: html, google-chrome, deep-linking

I am using Amazon-India affiliate program to monetize my website.
The situation is like this when someone visits my website on their mobile phone browser(specially Google chrome) and clicks on one of my affiliate link the links get open in Amazon App rather than opening in the same browser, In Indian amazon affiliate program you don't get commission on purchase made from app, so I want to keep user in the browser, when the user clicks on link it should open in amazon mobile site in new tab.

So, is there a way I can control the behavior of these deep-links being the mediator(publisher) between user and amazon and how? I have searched the whole Internet all I could find was this below link, but I don't know how to do this?

[Html disable android deep link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109005/html-disable-android-deep-link)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, this is behavior by design. If you own both a website and an app you can force all links to the website to be opened in the app by using a technique called [app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/) on devices which run at least Android 6.0. You can tell Amazon has set this up by looking at their [assetlinks](https://www.amazon.in/.well-known/assetlinks.json). Only Amazon and the device owner can change this behavior.

I'm not using Amazon affiliate links so I don't know the details of their program but there's not technical reason for them to not credit you for deep links that open the app.

Comment: I researched on the behavior of app links and found that: 
1. If the user paste or manually enter the amazon url in browser address bar, links tend to open in browser itself so not in amazon native app.
This is also verified in this article [link](https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/#so-what-works-and-what-doesn-t-or-shouldn-t-work)
2. target="_blank" doesn't help to keep the user into browser app links will direct them to amazon app, but if a user holds on to link and when "open in new tab" appears and clicks on that user remains in browser.

Comment: So if anyhow I can tell the chrome browser to open link in new tab not through target="blank" but (like the user is selecting by itself open in new tab) that should make it work.

I have very little knowledge of code but I found this below, Please let me know if it is possible.
1. [link](https://gist.github.com/idanen/284eb2b6c7efbaecb9b7)
2. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198442/angularjs-open-url-in-new-tab/32198740)
3. [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) this 1 may be for extensions. Let me know if I can make it of something.

Comment: The behavior you're describing is all by design. I don't see how the links you've provided are relevant for the question.